how can I keep my riverpod provider alive when going through different screens?
I would like to update the values in one page and get the updated value in next page.
here is my riverpod provider:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/models/coffee.dart';

Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'coffee.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE cart_provider(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, coffeeImage TEXT, CoffeeName TEXT, CoffeePrice REAL)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}

class CartNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Coffee>> {
  CartNotifier() : super([]);

  Future<void> loadCoffee() async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final data = await db.query('cart_provider');
    final coffees = data
        .map(
          (row) => Coffee(
            id: row['id'] as String,
            coffeeImage: row['coffeeImage'] as String,
            coffeeName: row['CoffeeName'] as String,
            coffeePrice: row['CoffeePrice'] as double,
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    state = coffees;
  }

  Future<void> addCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    if (state.contains(coffee) == true) {
      return;
    } else {
      final db = await _getDatabase();
      await db.insert(
        'cart_provider',
        {
          'id': coffee.id,
          'coffeeImage': coffee.coffeeImage,
          'CoffeeName': coffee.coffeeName,
          'CoffeePrice': coffee.coffeePrice,
        },
      );

      state = [...state, coffee];
    }
  }

  void removeCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    await db.delete(
      'cart_provider',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [coffee.id],
    );

    state = state.where((c) => c != coffee).toList();
  }

  bool isAdded(Coffee coffee) {
    if (state.contains(coffee)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

final cartProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CartNotifier, List<Coffee>>((ref) {
  final notifier = CartNotifier();
    return notifier;
});

I don't want my provider to dispose and clear the data automatically by switching between screens
if you need more information please tell me.

This provider is not an autoDispose provider, so it should live for the duration the app is running. So i don't know how to answer the question as it isn't behaving how Riverpod is supposed to work. I would put a breakpoint in return notifier; to see if it is re-running and maybe put a   ref.onDispose(() {print('disposing')}); before return notifier;. then put a breakpoint in the dispose callback and step up the stacktrace.
